# Interested in a short story contest taking place in games' story lines?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Some of the games we love on the site have such rich stories and well-developed worlds. Many of us spend good times (and sometimes not as good :) traveling, hacking, defeating and dying in these universes...

Would YOU want to participate in a writing contest wherein you pen (with quill or typewriter) a short narrative taking place in one of the selected games?

The best stories may be posted on the blog and be rewarded with jewels (no, not really jewels but you get the idea).

Judging can be based on voting by the community, or we could possibly coax real world creatives to guest arbitrate.

Did somebody say fan fiction?

Comment: I like it. Here's a nice resource that could help participants: http://writers.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Only if I can post under a pen name, lol.  My creative writing is not good enough for me to want to share it publicly :P

Comment: Depending on the game, I may be possible to act out the winning story...

Comment: Ah interesting @RonanForman, that could be AWESOME. And pen names are always allowed in writing- for all we know you could be Dr. Seuss.

Comment: Sounds like fun to me ;)

Comment: @MatthewRead - Matthew Write?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Lol, upvote for originality! I get "reading" jokes all the time but that's a new one.

Comment: OH MAN FAN FICTION MY FAVORITE

Comment: gah, your smiley doubles as a close parentheses. D: